# SetVirtualHostName within WebMessageReceived event handler doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

I'm trying to dynamically create an image within a WebView2, using a source passed in from the WebView2's containing application.

The source image exists on an arbitrary location on the filesystem. To allow the WebView2 to access the image, I'm using [SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.setvirtualhostnametofoldermapping?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1185.39), which maps a hostname within the webview to some folder.

I want this to happen only after some interaction from inside the webview, using `postMessage` and the [**WebMessageReceived** event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.webmessagereceived), as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf#step-9---communication-between-host-and-web-content).

If I call **SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping** outside of the **WebMessageReceived** handler, even after I've navigated to the HTML using `NavigateToString`, the webview loads the image.

But if I call **SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping** within the **WebMessageReceived** handler:

```cs
webview.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += (s, e) => {
    webview.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping(
        "assets",
        @"C:\path\to\folder",
        CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.Allow
    );
    webview.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsString(@"breakpoint.bmp");
};
```

the webview can't find the image; it fails with:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

**How can I debug this? Are there any other alternatives I could use to do something similar?**

---

XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="_testWebviewDialogs.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf">
    <wv:WebView2 x:Name="webview" />
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;

namespace _testWebviewDialogs;
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += async (s, e) => await initializeAsync();
    }

    private async Task initializeAsync() {
        await webview.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
        webview.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += (s, e) => {
            webview.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping(
                "assets",
                @"C:\path\to\folder",
                CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.Allow
            );
            webview.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsString(@"breakpoint.bmp");
        };

        var html = await File.ReadAllTextAsync("container.html");
        webview.NavigateToString(html);
    }
}
```

`container.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button id="button1">Click me</button>
    <img id ="img1" src="" />
    <script>
        document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener('click', ev => {
            chrome.webview.postMessage('source');
        });
        window.chrome.webview.addEventListener('message', event => {
            document.getElementById('img1').src = `https://assets/${event.data}`;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2456) for this. Per the response, this behavior is documented:

> As the resource loaders for the current page might have already been created and running, changes to the mapping might not be applied to the current page and a reload of the page is needed to apply the new mapping. ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.setvirtualhostnametofoldermapping?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1210.39#remarks))

But it's possible to create (and recreate) a symbolic link to different target paths, and map the virtual host name to that symbolic link. The virtual host mapping uses the current symlink target.

```cs
var symlinkPath =
    Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location!
        )!,
        "assets"
    );

Directory.CreateDirectory(symlinkPath);

webview.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping(
    "assets",
    symlinkPath,
    CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.Allow
);

webview.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += (s, e) => {
    Directory.Delete(symlinkPath);
    Directory.CreateSymbolicLink(symlinkPath, @"C:\path\to\target\directory");
    webview.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsString(@"breakpoint.bmp");
};
```